# Movie in Matlab, difference between frames

Tags: matlab

I have to make movie in Matlab using some images, I did it:

```
ImageList = {'AT3_1m4_01.tif', 'AT3_1m4_02.tif', 'AT3_1m4_03.tif', ... 
'AT3_1m4_04.tif', 'AT3_1m4_05.tif', 'AT3_1m4_06.tif', ... 
'AT3_1m4_07.tif', 'AT3_1m4_08.tif', 'AT3_1m4_09.tif','AT3_1m4_10.tif' }; 

 writerObj = VideoWriter('film22.avi'); 


fps = 1; 
writerObj.FrameRate = fps; 


open(writerObj); 


 for iImage = 1:10 
  Frame = imread(ImageList{iImage}); 

   writeVideo(writerObj,Frame); 
end 


close(writerObj); 
implay('film22.avi');
```

now, I have to find all pixels, where difference between first and next frames is smaller than 25. Have you had any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be to add something like the following in your loop. Basically create a dummy matrix of dimensions (Height,Width,9) (i.e. # of images -1) and assign a value of one to pixels in which the difference is less than 25.

```
ImageForInfo = imread(ImageList{1}); % Get infos about images, i.e. width and height.

ImageHeight = size(ImageForInfo,1);
ImageWidth = size(ImageForInfo,2);

DiffMatrix = zeros(ImageHeight,ImageWidth,length(ImageList)-1); % Initialize matrix

DummyDiffFrames = zeros(size(ImageForInfo)); % Dummy matrix for finding pixel values that interest you.

for iImage = 1:10 

   Frame = imread(ImageList{iImage}); 
   writeVideo(writerObj,Frame); 


  if iImage < 10
     DummyDiffFrames(find(imread(ImageList{iImage}) - imread(ImageList{iImage+1}) < 25)) = 1; % Assign 1 where pixel difference is less than 25.

     DiffMatrix(:,:,iImage) = DummyDiffFrames;
  end

end
```

It looks complicated because of the calls to imread in the loop, but you could of course simplify by storing the frames before the loop in a cell array, and then simply index into the array for computing the difference. If it's not clear please ask.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I'm getting this error and I don't know why: Undefined function or method 'minus' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in ==> Untitled12 at 24
DiffMatrix = zeros(size(ImageList{1},1),size(ImageList{1},2),length(ImageList-1)); %
Initialize matrix

Comment: oups I placed the bracket at the wrong place! I will edit it in my answer.

Comment: I'm really sorry for wasting your time, but I still have error, different this time: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in ==> Untitled12 at 30
     DiffMatrix(:,:,iImage) = DummyDiffFrames;

Comment: ok I see why; I had in mind that "ImageList" contained the actual frames, but since it contains their names, using size(ImageList{1}) returns the length in characters of the name, which we don't want. I'll modify it.Sorry about that!

Comment: thank you very much, you've helped me a lot! I have one more question:I need to delete all holes with area bigger than 50px. To be honest I have no idea how to do it!

Comment: Ok sounds interesting! I would post this as a new question so that more people will look at it and give answers. If possible provide as many details as you can about what you want to achieve, and maybe post pictures of what images you have or what you expect to get. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/index.html), you can take advantage of [`imabsdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imabsdiff.html), which is based on a mex function written in C. An example:

```
Frame1 = imread(ImageList{1});
writeVideo(writerObj,Frame1);
for iImage = 2:10 
    Frame = imread(ImageList{iImage});

    Z_25 = imabsdiff(Frame1,Frame) > 25; % Difference with respect to first frame
    bwDiffImg = double(Z_25);            % Black & White difference image
    % Do something with your diff image or use idx=find(Z_25) to find indices...

    writeVideo(writerObj,Frame);
end
```

If you need to find indices within `Z_25` above, check out the documentation for [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html). Or you can use `Z_25` directly via [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1). Your question isn't specific about what exactly you want in this respect and you already accepted an answer, so I'm not going to try to guess. The [`imsubtract`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imsubtract.html) might also be useful to you.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I don't really need to do anything with pixels which are found, I just need to find them (those with difference 25) :)

Comment: nice one @horchler I did not know about imabsdiff that's good to know!